Программа продолжает работать после закрытия окна
У меня программа с 2 стейджами и при нажатии на кнопку, мы переключаемся на второй, если мы закрываем окно будучи еще на первой стейдже, то программа завершается, но если мы закрываем окно на втором, то программа почему то продолжает работу.
public void Switchto2(javafx.event.ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    Parent root = new FXMLLoader().load(getClass().getResource("StageFight.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) ((Node)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    stage.getOnCloseRequest();
}

